# Skip Model Validation in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, validation, sails.js, waterline

Is it possible to skip model validation when saving objects in Sails.js? I'm writing a scheduling application. I have a validation on my `Event` model that requires its `DateTime` property to be in the future. For unit testing, I would like to include some fixtures that have dates in the past, simulating events gone by. I'm using mocha for testing and [barrels.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/barrels) for fixtures. If I try to add a fixture with a DateTime in the past, I get a validation error in my beforeEach hook and my tests fail. I can't find any way around it without the option to just skip the validation when saving, and I can't find anything about that in the docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this feature is not available in ver 0.11.x . You can achieve it by using the Model.query() or Model.native (depending on your adapter) as these will skip all validations and hooks.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/native.html
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/query.html

---

Their are other work arounds, but since your just adding data for testing, then this method should work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Am I right in assuming that there's no equivalent for the sails-disk adapter?

Comment: Ya, I don't think so. Another solution is that if your using the "after" validation, it can be a function that returns a value based on a setting, environment or value passed with the data. So you can make that date equal last year if your testing.

Comment: @Meeker, I am having an issue in sailsjs, can you have a look? Here's the  question [validations-for-associative-models-sailsjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202056/validations-for-associative-models-sailsjs)   Thanks!