# Validations for associative models sailsJs

Tags: javascript, validation, sails.js

I am trying to build a REST API on **sailsjs v0.11.0**, I am looking for a way to validate all POST requests. Validation works for simple models.

Simple model example:
**category.js**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,    // this works, the POST data is validated, if this field is missing, sails responds with an error json
            unique: true
        }
    }
}
```

Associative one to many model example where validation doesnt work:

**Chapter.js**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        categoryId: 'integer',
        pages: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true     // Sails saves the record to DB even if this field is missing.
        },
        owner: {
            model: 'Upload'
        }
    }

};
```

**Upload.js**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        draftId: 'integer',
        chapters: {
            collection: 'Chapter',
            via: 'owner'
        }
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

I got it to work with the following **updated Chapter.js** model, but if the associated model fails validation, the sails server responds with a 500 status and a error json as shown below, While this is not an error, It should have sent a 400 status.

Updated Chapter.js:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        categoryId: {
            type: 'integer',
            required: true
        },
        pages: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        owner: {
            model: 'Upload'
        }
    }
};
```

The Error with 500 status:

```
{
  "error": "E_UNKNOWN",
  "status": 500,
  "summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
  "raw": [
    {
      "type": "insert",
      "collection": "chapter",
      "values": {
        "name": "chapeterOne",
        "pages": "2,3,4,5",
        "owner": 12
      },
      "err": {
        "error": "E_VALIDATION",
        "status": 400,
        "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
        "model": "Chapter",
        "invalidAttributes": {
          "categoryId": [
            {
              "rule": "integer",
              "message": "`undefined` should be a integer (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
            },
            {
              "rule": "required",
              "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to make the error message more sensible?

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not an error. Give us inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs.

Comment: @TravisWebb, Can you help me with the 500 status code?

Comment: You're talking about a different thing now. At first you said this had to do with `pages`, but your `categoryId` validation is failing.

Comment: Secondly: `This doesnt work, Sails accepts the POST`. You're sending a POST request, sails is going to "accept" it even if it consists of complete crap. The validators are run on the server, and that's where you need to handle the error and then inform the client.

Comment: If you think there is a bug, I'd file it in the waterline repository.

Comment: @TravisWebb, Yeah, I get that it is going to accept the post, but what I mean is that the validation process should return with a failure of not being able to validate the posted data with the model. I really dont know if this is a bug or due to me being new to sailsjs. If you have understood my problem and think its a bug, Please do file it to waterline. Thanks!